# What's a "living story"?

Tags: fallen-london

Every now and then, I complete an Opportunity card and it states, `A living story will begin soon!` What is a "living story" and how would I complete one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "living story" message indicates that in anywhere from a few hours to a few days, you will receive a message in your Messages tab allowing you to progress in the story.